# Rewrite URL by variables

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a search form with: 
1) Search by (all the time set - it's a select form with selected='true')
2) Input (with accept only A-Z,a-z,0-9)
3) And other 2 select form like first

You can search with all 3 (except point 2) and I want to rewrite URL for 3 variables.
When I have all variables rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^servers/([a-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([A-Z-]+)/?$   servers.php?query=$1&matching=$2&playing=$3&location=$4 [NC,L]
```

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^servers/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([A-Z-]+)/?$   servers.php?query=$1&playing=$2&location=$3 [NC,L]
```

but doesn't work. Can you help me ?

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['searchservers'])){
    $okGame = 0;
    $okLocation = 0;
    //Search Type Filter
    switch($_POST['searchtype']){
        case 'nameorip':
        case 'map':
            $query = $_POST['searchtype'];
        break;
        default:
            $query = "nameorip";
        break;
    }
    // Sentence Filter
    if(isset($_POST['matching'])){
        $matching = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $_POST['matching']);
    }
    // Game Filter
    $getGames = DB::conn()->query("SELECT abbr FROM `games`");
        while($gamee = $getGames->fetch_assoc()){
            if($_POST['game'] == $gamee['abbr']){
                $playing = $gamee['abbr'];
                $okGame = 1;
            }
        }
        if($okGame == 0){
            $playing = "allgames";
        }
        // Location Filter
        if(strlen($_POST['location']) == 2){
            $location = preg_replace('/[^A-Z\-]/', '', $_POST['location']);
            $okLocation = 1;
        }
        if($okLocation == 0){
            $location = "alllocations";
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['matching'])){
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/servers/'.$query.'/'.$playing.'/'.$location.'/">';
        } else {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/servers/'.$query.'/'.$matching.'/'.$playing.'/'.$location.'/">';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it might be handy to actually see the form as well and also to know how the form is submitted because generally when you submit a form via GET it will be of the form var=value&var2=val2 etc rather than val/val2/val3 etc so I suspect that what you want to do is dynamically redirect to a pretty url given a standard form submission with typical querystring?

Comment: No. My form has POST method because, firstly, I case of non-empty input, i prefer to use preg_match for symbols (like $%@ etc.). Then I check if second and third select form have specific form. In the end, after preg_match for symbols I check if that input is empty or contains blank space (with ctype_space). Then i do this:    `if(!isset($_POST['matching'])){echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/servers/'.$query.'/'.$playing.'/'.$location.'/">';} else {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/servers/'.$query.'/'.$matching.'/'.$playing.'/'.$location.'/">';}` -No space left-

Comment: so you submit using post and then redirect using php and generate the desired url structure? adding the form and some of the logic to redirect to the question rather than a comment would be good.

Comment: I added code in first post. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^servers/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([A-Z-]+)/?$ servers.php?query=$1&playing=$2&location=$3 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^servers/([a-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([A-Z-]+)/?$ servers.php?query=$1&matching=$2&playing=$3&location=$4 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

It seemed to work when I navigated to http://localhost/servers/a/b/c/d/ or http://localhost/servers/a/b/c/

Make sure you actually have servers.php in your root directory or change Rewritebase accordingly.

Comment: My `Rewrite` system works fine if I have all 4 variables ! I want to `Rewrite` for 3 variables. Read again first post and comments.